# Where to store the state of a complex form in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react, graphql

Let us consider a complex form of registering a driver and owner.

The driver will have all these fields:

```
driver = {
firstName: "xyz",
lastName: "abc",
phone: "1234",
email: "m@g.com,
licence: "xy1234"
}
```

And owner has the following fields:

```
owner = {
firstName: "xyz",
lastName: "abc",
phone: "1234",
email: "m@g.com,
vehicle: "1234"
}
```

Notice how they both have 4 inputs in common so it makes sense to create a reusable component called User, so our component heirarchy becomes

```
Driver
User
licence input
```

At this point if I want to make a post request on the driver data I will have to store the state in the driver and update the state of the driver whenever my inputs in the user component or the licence field changes (`onChange`).

The catch with this is that the the entire driver component re-renders whenever a single input changes and this creates a problem when you have a lot of nested components (since the parent re-renders all its children whenever one of them changes)

What is the best design pattern for this solution?

Comment: I think this is more of a question for Stackoverflow. Make sure that you provide a code example to give a more clear situation on what you are dealing with. 

Quick hint: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: @J.D. I did post it on stack overflow but it got closed saying that it was opinion based. that is why i posted it over here